# preg_match_all loop match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$html = "<p class='images'>
<img src='URL1'>
<img src='URL2'>
<img src='URL3'>
<img src='URL4'>

</p>

<p><img src='ThisNot'></p>
";
preg_match_all('/<p class=\'images\'>(?:\s*<img src=\'([^\']*)\'>\s*)*\s*<\/p>/ism', $html,$arr);


print_r($arr);
```

OUTPUT

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p class='images'> <img src='URL1'> <img src='URL2'> <img src='URL3'> <img src='URL4'>

</p>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => URL4
        )

)
```

The regex * only returns the last match in preg_match_all The match has occurred but has not returned to the output array How can I get all the URLs?

It worked when I tried to use two preg_match_all the first to get

content and then match with all the images but I would like to get with just one

Comment: Why not use DOMDocument? http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a one-liner regex. When a new group is found in a repeating match, it does not store the previous group. What's wrong with using two `preg_match_all` though?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with DOMDocument:

```
$html = "<p class='images'>
<img src='URL1'>
<img src='URL2'>
<img src='URL3'>
<img src='URL4'>

</p>

<p><img src='ThisNot'></p>
";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
$urls = array();
foreach($tags as $p){
    if($p->getAttribute('class') == "images"){
        $imgs = $p->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach($imgs as $img){
            $urls[] = $img->getAttribute('src');
        }
    }
}
print_r($urls);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => URL1
    [1] => URL2
    [2] => URL3
    [3] => URL4
)
```